# Unable to connect Xampp on VSAT(Very small Aperture Terminal) network?

Tags: php, networking, windows-7-x64, web-operating-system

I work on a company with network using  VSAT(Very Small Aperture Terminal) and Cable network. And then, temporary server i use is Windows 7 64-bit. If i access that server from cable network nothing error show on my website. But if i access my website from VSAT show error

> ```
> The server at 192.168.30.20:1706/IWI is taking too long to respond.
>
> The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
> If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer’s network connection.
> If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web
> ```

I had try to change anything port.is there something wrong with my setting in my Xampp or my Operating System?.